# How to add LatLng to NameValuePairs

Tags: android

*I have created asyntask to send some details to my web page and handle it
*I have successfully sent string values to my page
*But now problem is now i want send variable **markerPosition** which is the type of **LatLng**
*Eclipse suggest me to change it to String but i know It's not a solution
*Is there any other way to send it..?

```
private class sendToWebsite extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    String reverseString;
    String username,Place,Status;
    LatLng markerPosition;

    public sendToWebsite(String userName, String place_text,
            String status_text, LatLng mPosition) {

        username = userName;
        Place = place_text;
        Status = status_text;
        markerPosition = mPosition;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String URL = "url here";

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    1);
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place", Place));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", Status));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("position", markerPosition));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            reverseString = response;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return reverseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String flag = "success";
        if (result.equals(flag)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LatLng is an object that cannot simply be packaged and sent in an Http request as is.

You will need to extract the latitude and longitude from the LatLng in order to send it via an Http request as Strings. For example:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(markerPosition.latitude)));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(markerPosition.longitude)));
```

On your backend, convert the received values back into doubles and process them.

Answer (score 1):

remove the position value then create a new parameter in your site names latitude and longitude then add the latitude and longitude of the marker to the `nameValuePairs`

remove:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("position", markerPosition));
```

add a new pair:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", markerPosition.latitude + ""));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", markerPosition.longitude +""));
```